# Angular 2 two-way binding is not working with JSON Object

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject, two-way-binding

I am trying to access json data through shared service which is "Customer.service.ts". I am able to get all the result till end thats is (from CustomerComponent to CustomerComponentPopup). But, Somehow two way binding is not working. 
Below are my files and I am also posting my console output

Shared Service **customers.service.ts**

```
setCurrentCustomerSubject(customerIdSubject: number) {
    this.customerIdSubject.next(customerIdSubject);

}
getCurrentCustomerSubject(): CustomersPersonal {

  var customerId : any;

  this.customerIdSubject.subscribe(customerId1=>customerId=customerId1);
  return CUST_PERSONAL.find(x => x.id === customerId);

}
```

Component File, Onclick of showModal() function I am trying to open bootstrap modal popup.

Component File  **customer.component.ts**
    //

```
@ViewChild(customersPersonalDetailComponentPopup)
childModal: customersPersonalDetailComponentPopup;


 showModal(customerId: number) {

    this.customerService.setCurrentCustomerSubject(customerId);    
    this.editCustId = customerId;
    this.childModal.showChildModal();
  }
```

Booststap Modal popup Component **customersPersonalDetailComponentPopup**

showChildModal function will open the modal popup. I am getting my desire record in "this.selectedCustomer".

```
public showChildModal():void {

   this.selctedCustomer = this.customerService.getCurrentCustomerSubject() 
   console.log(this.selctedCustomer);
   this.childModal.show();
```

}

Ouput of the code **console.log(this.selctedCustomer);**

> {id: 13, name: "Bombasto", address: "Nice Address2", phoneNumber: "111111", qualification: "edu3"}
>           address : "Nice Address2"
>           id : 13
>           name : "Bombasto"
>           phoneNumber : "111111"
>           qualification : "edu3"
>           **proto** :
>           constructor:ƒ Object()
>           hasOwnProperty:ƒ hasOwnProperty()
>           isPrototypeOf:ƒ isPrototypeOf()
>           propertyIsEnumerable:ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
>           toLocaleString:ƒ toLocaleString()
>           toString:ƒ ()
>           valueOf:ƒ valueOf()
>           **defineGetter**:ƒ **defineGetter**()
>           **defineSetter**:ƒ **defineSetter**()
>           **lookupGetter**:ƒ **lookupGetter**()
>           **lookupSetter**:ƒ **lookupSetter**()
>           get **proto**:ƒ **proto**()
>           set **proto**:ƒ **proto**()

This the html file code **popup.html**

```
 <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" [(ngModel)]="selctedCustomer.name"
           #name="ngModel" required  minlength="4" maxlength="24" value="{{selctedCustomer.name}}">
```

`[(ngModel)]="selctedCustomer.name"` is not displaying anything but it is displaying value with this notation `{{selctedCustomer?.name}}`

I dont know where I am wrong in accessing values from json object

Comment: Does getCurrentCustomerSubject make an asynchronous call? If so, you need to display the modal after the promise resolves.

Comment: As @Mike Feltman pointed out, you should return your subject from your function getCurrentCustomerSubject(), and subscribe to it in the component opening your modal. This way, you can (from your component) open your modal **after** the asynchronous call has finished, otherwise your data will be null by the time your modal is instantiated.

Comment: Thanks Mike & @MaximeFlament **getCurrentCustomerSubject** is not making asynchronous call. <br/><br/>
 I m trying to share value of **customerId** from "customer.component" to **customer.component.popup** and for that I have used **Customer.Service** and in that I have made **customerId** as an Observerable like below  <br/><br/>
`customerIdSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);` <br/><br/>
 From **getCurrentCustomeSubject**, I m just trying to retrieve the record matched with that customerId. <br/>MikeFeltman how do I implement the way you explained. If possible please give example.

Comment: Are you exposing an observable of the subject inside the customer service? what's it called? if not you should, and instead of "getCustomerSubject", you subscribe directly to the exposed observable inside showModal window ... subscribe by nature is async, nothing set outside of it matters to it